# Wise to switch Media Library storage from File to Database?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, webdeploy

I have my Media Library stored as physical files. When a Sitecore user publishes an item, the files are dispersed to a number of CD servers using WebDeploy.

I would like to switch to Database storage due to some performance issues with WebDeploy, but I'm concerned that it may be too late. I have hundreds of physical Media Library files already attached to items in Sitecore.

How will Sitecore react to switching storage after the fact? Can it handle the two modes simultaneously, or must I migrate all my files into the DB?

Comment: I am assuming this worked for you.  Did you have to tweak anything to make it work?  I can use the MediaConversionTool to pull images out of the DB, but it won't put them in. There are no errors, just an extra image in the Media directory with _001 appended to the file name.  http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=46215#46215 for more details.

Comment: Are you going from DB to file system? I haven't tried it in that direction. It appears to work going from file system to DB.

Comment: That's odd.  I have the opposite behaviour to you.  DB->File works fine.  File->DB fails with no errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would make the switch, its makes less problems with the media in the database, and less things to keep track of, when running in a Multi server environment.

See more pros and cons [here](http://firebreaksice.com/storing-sitecore-media-in-the-database-vs-the-file-system/)

You can very easy, make all existing media items, to a database media.

I have used this tool, to make the migration:
https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Media_Conversion_Tool.aspx